# list append issue inside "for" loop

Tags: python, for-loop, arraylist, append, infinite-loop

I was trying to solve a problem that contains a code part similar to this. But whenever I tried to execute the script, it turns out to be an infinite loop. What is the reason for this issue and how can I solve it?

```
a=[1,2]
for i in a:
  a.append(i)
  print("Infinite")
```

I tried this program locally on my computer and Google Colab, but in both cases. But instead of appending values 1, 2 to list `a`, it works differently.

I created a copy of `a` by assigning `z=a` and changed the structure of `for` loop like this:

```
z=a
for i in z:
   a.append(i)
```

But the issue remains the same:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is happening is every for every iteration of the loop, a new value is added to the list `a`. This means there is always a new element in the list after every iteration, meaning the loop will never finish.

As for your copy of `a`, that doesn't exactly create a copy of `a`. `z=a` simply references the variable `a`, and so modifying `z` also modifies `a`.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't change the structure of a container while iterating it. Here, you're adding to the end of `a` while iterating it. That will go on forever.

You were on the right track with your try to fix it. The problem is though, `z=a` doesn't create a copy of the list; it creates a new reference to the same list.

You need to make a copy explicitly:

```
z=a[:]  # Copy via slice notation
for i in z:
   a.append(i)
```

Or just `extend` `a` with itself:

```
a.extend(a)
print(a)  # [1, 2, 1, 2]
```

Or multiply it:

```
a *= 2
```